# Excel - exctract "zeros" data - Small modification

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I would like to add small modification to [[previous question]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77673025/4841876).

How can I add a condition to the main body of the code to skip cells with 'zero' that have a colored background?

When checking cells, the modification should ignore those that have any background color (marked in red), and only take into account those that have no background formatting (marked in blue).

**Example:**

[image]

**My code looks now like this:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub OB_Raport_brakow()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim arrData As Variant
Dim rngData As Range
Dim arrRes, iR As Long
Dim LastRow As Long, wsOB As Worksheet
Dim DataRange As Range

' Sprawdza jaka jest ostatnia linia tabeli przestawnej
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Set wsOB = Sheets("OB")

' Określa zakres komorek do sprawdzenia
' zakres półautomatyczny - początek na sztywno, a koniec na ostatni rząd tabeli przestawnej +1
' by ostatnie "zero" nie uciekało z raportu

' Set rngData = wsOB.Range("B4:R" & LastRow + 1)


    ' Deklaruj zmienną do przechowywania wyboru użytkownika
    Dim strCol As String
    

    ' Pyta jaka kolumna będzie ogranicznikiem do sprawdzania braków
    
    strCol = InputBox("Podaj kolumnę, do której mają zostać pobrane dane:", "Wybór kolumny")

    ' Ustaw rngData na zakres danych
    Set rngData = wsOB.Range("B4:" & strCol & LastRow + 1)


arrData = rngData.Value
ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData) * 31, 0)
iR = 0

For j = LBound(arrData, 2) + 2 To UBound(arrData, 2)
    If arrData(4, j) = "T" Then
        For i = LBound(arrData) + 4 To UBound(arrData)
            If arrData(i, j) = 0 And Not IsEmpty(arrData(i, j)) Then
                iR = iR + 1
                arrRes(iR, 0) = arrData(i, 2) & "-" & arrData(i, 1) & "-" & Format(arrData(2, j), "dd.mm.yyyy")
                
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next

On Error GoTo Catch
Try:
'Próbuje wybrać arkusz o wskaznej nazwie
    Sheets("OB Rp").Select
    GoTo Finally
Catch:
'Jeśli focus na wskazany arkusz się nie uda to tworzy go
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("OB")).Name = "OB Rp"
Finally:
On Error GoTo 0

'Aktywuje arkusz do raportu, czyści go a następnie uzupełnia danymi
Sheets("OB Rp").Activate
'Cells.Clear
Range("B1:D600").ClearContents
Range("B1:B" & iR).Value = arrRes

'Rodziela na kolumny B i C, to co znajduje się w kolumnie A za pomocą separatora "-"
'Dim arrTmp() As String
'For i = 1 To iR
'    arrTmp = Split(arrRes(i, 0), "-")
'    Range("A" & i).Value = arrTmp(0)
'    Range("B" & i).Value = arrTmp(1)
'    Range("C" & i).Value = arrTmp(2)
'Next

'Na koniec sortuje A-Z według kolumny z nazwiskiem
Range("B1").Sort Key1:=Range("B1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Comment: To check if a cell is formatted with white, check `cell.Interior.color = vbWhite or cell.Interior.color = xlNone`. However, the modification is not so small because you read the data into an array, and the array will only hold the values, not anything else (like formatting). And as don't read the data starting from cells(1, 1) ("=A1"), you will need to take care of the offset so you check the correct cell.

Comment: Could it work on the principle that only those cells that are zero during checking and have no background color will be included in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add an `If` statement to check whether the fill color of the cell is `vbWhite`.
- `rngData` begins from `B4`, so there are row and column offsets to obtain the cell reference.

```vb
If arrData(i, j) = 0 And Not IsEmpty(arrData(i, j)) Then
    If wsOB.Cells(i + 3, j + 1).Interior.Color = vbWhite Then
        iR = iR + 1
        arrRes(iR, 0) = arrData(i, 2) & "-" & arrData(i, 1) & "-" & Format(arrData(2, j), "dd.mm.yyyy")
    End If
End If
```